# Django 2.13: NoReverseMatch at /basic_app/user_login/

Tags: python, django

I've almost completed the course on Udemy on web development but stumbled at the very last step. I really hope someone will be able to help me out as this seems to be a very simple thing that I'm struggling with.

The problem seems to be with HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index')) that is triggered when a user clicks on the Log In link.

Thank you very much!

Error is triggered at http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/user_login/

```
NoReverseMatch at /basic_app/user_login/
Reverse for 'basic_app/user_login' not found. 'basic_app/user_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Error during template rendering
In template /Users/maxa/Dropbox/workspace/2018/projects/python-django-udemy-bootcamp/myplayground/Django_level_5/learning_users/templates/basic_app/base.html, error at line 6
```

**Project's urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.urls import path
from basic_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^basic_app/',include('basic_app.urls')),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
]
```

**App's urls.py (basic_app/urls.py):**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from basic_app import views

# TEMPLATE RULES
app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
    url(r'^user_login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
]
```

**App's views.py (basic_app/views.py):**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request,'basic_app/index.html')

def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()

            registered = True

        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered})

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is not active.")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to log in and failed")
            print("Username: {}. Password: {}".format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse("invalid login details supplied!")

    else:
        return render(request,'basic_app/login.html',{})

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

**App's base.html (templates/basic_app/base.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body> <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container"><ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="navbar-brand" class="nav-link">Home</a></li> <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}" class="nav-link">Admin</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'basic_app:register' %}" class="nav-link">Register</a></li>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="nav-link">Log Out</li>

{% else %}

<li><a href="{% url 'basic_app:user_login' %}" class="nav-link">Log In</a></li>

{% endif %}


    </ul></div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

{% block body_block %}
{% endblock %}

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**App's login.html (templates/basic_app/login.html):**

```
{% extends 'basic_app/base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}

<div class="jumbotron">

    <h1>Please login</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'basic_app/user_login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Enter Username">

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">

        <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
    </form>


</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: In place of form `action="{ % url 'basic_app/user_login' % }" `, make it empty `action="  "` in app's login html. And also you can simply use redirect in place of `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo in `templates/basic_app/login.html` in the form's action attribute. Change `basic_app/user_login` to `basic_app:user_login`

```
<form action="{% url 'basic_app:user_login' %}" method="post">
```

Comment: This helped, thank you very much!

One of those "how on earth could I miss this?!" moments for sure...